# gcc cross compiling for raspberry pi /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, raspbian

On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I'm cross-compiling for raspberry pi. When I run any built executable on the pi, I get this linking error:

`` /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found ``

I get this error cross-compiling with gcc-9, gcc-10, gcc-11, and gcc-12.

The pi is running 'Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)'. What's the best was to resolve this issue? Will a different version of Raspbian resolve this issue, or do I need to install a newer version of glibc?

Comment: Glibc → libc6 *is* your OS (together with the kernel) and cannot be changed. Generally when compiling for old: Use "older", e.g. Ubuntu 20.04. ..... No stable Debian has yet libc6 - 2.34  https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=libc6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by finding the right pre-built cross-compiler for raspberry pi bullseye [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberry-pi-cross-compilers/).